# Is there any way to draw a table using Raphael js library

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am using Raphael JS to creating a ERD like tool, but don't know to to create a table like instance by using Raphael.

Comment: What sort of table do you mean?

Comment: you'll need .rect and .text methods

Comment: I mean the menu like table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raphael can draw anything, but if you're doing a lot of manual creation of tables and so forth than you're probably fighting the framework. My favorite aspect of the library is that is works so seamlessly with traditional HTML, CSS and Javascript. I would strong suggest taking what you want from HCJ and using Raphael for whatever that can't easily do.

Answer (score 1):

```
paper = new Raphael(0,0,500,500);

var x = 100;
var y = 50;
var height = 50
var width = 100;

WriteTableRow(x,y,width*2,height,paper,"TOP Title");
y= y+height;
WriteTableRow(x,y,width,height,paper,"Score,Player");
y= y+height;
for (i=1;i<=4;i++)
{
var k;
k = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 + 1 - 5) + 5);
WriteTableRow(x,y,width,height,paper,i+","+ k + "");
y= y+height;
}


function WriteTableRow(x,y,width,height,paper,TDdata)
{
    var TD = TDdata.split(",");
    for (j=0;j<TD.length;j++)
    {
        var rect = paper.rect(x,y,width,height).attr({"fill":"white","stroke":"red"});
        paper.text(x+width/2, y+height/2, TD[j]) 
        x = x + width;
    }
}
```

//http://jsfiddle.net/LG5zn/116/